Unable to implement MediaRouteButton in Jetpack Compose
I have been working on a POC where I have to cast the screen of my app to a chromecast built in tv whenever I am using the MediaRouteButton I am getting a crash and the error says "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: background can not be translucent" I have also put in a custom theme and color to the MediaROuteButton as given below
@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        AndroidView(
            modifier = Modifier,
            factory = { ctx ->
                val themedContext = ContextThemeWrapper(ctx, R.style.AppTheme)
                val button = MediaRouteButton(themedContext)
                button.setBackgroundColor(ctx.getColor(android.R.color.black))
                CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(themedContext, button)
                button
            },
            update = { button ->
                    button.performClick()
            }
        )
    }
}

This is the function I am using where I am setting custom style and color
But I am still getting the translucent error

You are probably not using the correct theme for the MediaRouteButton to work (it uses the primaryColor set in the Activity theme as a background color). Make sure, you are using the @style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar theme inside your AndroidManifest.xml. It should look like something like this:
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        ...
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>


Actually I was using the exact theme required but I am still having the same error but now I am actually doing everything in a custom way

Bootstrapping
First of all, you'll need these two libraries
# libs.versions.toml
google-cast-framework = { module = "com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework", version = "22.0.0" }
androidx-mediarouter = { module = "androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter", version = "1.7.0" }

Also in your build.gradle.kts:
// build.gradle.kts
implementation(libs.google.cast.framework)
implementation(libs.androidx.mediarouter)

Then you'll need a style definition, necessarily something that's based on AppCompat. This is a requirement of the Cast SDK, unfortunately. Since you'll probably hide the built-in button of the SDK, and you would like to use your own, the actual colours might be irrelevant.
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Styling for google cast. Using an AppCompat based theme is a must, otherwise the
         built-in stuff from the Cast SDK won't work -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#03535E</item>
        <item name="mediaRouteButtonTint">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
</resources>

Just as it's documented, you need your own `CastOptionsProvider too:
// CastOptionsProvider.kt

/**
 * Provides the CastOptions for the Cast SDK. Referenced in the AndroidManifest.xml.
 */
class CastOptionsProvider : OptionsProvider {
    override fun getCastOptions(context: Context): CastOptions {
        return CastOptions.Builder()
            .setReceiverApplicationId(context.getString({{YOUR_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID}}))
            .build()
    }

    override fun getAdditionalSessionProviders(context: Context): List<SessionProvider>? {
        return null
    }
}

And in your manifest you need to reference the provider:
<application>
    ...
    <meta-data
        android:name=
            "com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
        android:value="com.foo.CastOptionsProvider" />
</application>

Those were the foundations, and now the actual tricks...
Something to keep tabs on your own MediaRouteButton instances
In this step we'll do two things:

Define our own extended version of MediaRouteButton
Create a singleton that will keep track of the instances of our custom buttons

We need to do so, because these buttons can be created and destroyed dynamically, so we need to explicitly know when these events happen.
import android.content.Context
import androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton

/**
 * An extended version of the cast framework's built-in [MediaRouteButton] that allows us to keep
 * track of the valid instances. The idea is to bind the addition and removal of the button to the
 * event when the button is attached and detached from the window respectively.
 */
class CustomMediaRouteButton(context: Context): MediaRouteButton(context) {
    override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow()
        MediaRouteButtonManager.add(this)
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow()
        MediaRouteButtonManager.remove(this)
    }
}

/**
 * A helper singleton to store the valid [CustomMediaRouteButton] instances. Since these buttons can be
 * created and destroyed dynamically, we need to keep track of the valid instances.
 */
object MediaRouteButtonManager {
    private val buttons = mutableListOf<CustomMediaRouteButton>()

    fun add(button: CustomMediaRouteButton) {
        buttons.add(button)
    }

    fun remove(button: CustomMediaRouteButton) {
        buttons.remove(button)
    }

    // Since we only want to fake a click on the button, it's enough to always interact with the last one
    val current: CustomMediaRouteButton?
        get() = buttons.lastOrNull()
}

Initializing everything inside your Activity
This is the place where you have to initialize the CastContext, and also where you have to create your custom MediaRouteButton instances. And this is where AndroidView from Compose comes into the picture, because we have to attach the button to a window (even if it won't be visible) in order to make the built-in provisioning logic kick in. The AndroidView composable lets you wrap an Android view and use it in your Compose UI, and it also provides you with some lifecycle callbacks, like onRelease, update that are especially useful in this case.
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastButtonFactory
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext
import com.foo.MediaRouteButtonManager
import com.foo.CustomMediaRouteButton

class ExampleActivity : FragmentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Initializing the Cast button and the initial CastContext
        val mediaRouteButton = try {
            val button = CustomMediaRouteButton(this)
            // Lazy load Google Cast context. It needs to be done here where we have a Context,
            // otherwise we won't have a CastContext "later" in the application
            CastContext.getSharedInstance(this)
            CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(applicationContext, button)
            button
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            // Casting is probably not supported on this device
            null
        }

        setContent {
                mediaRouteButton?.let { mRButton ->
                    // The MediaRouteButton needs to be rendered (more precisely, attached to
                    // the window) in order to make it able to interact with it. The onRelease and
                    // update callbacks are used to add and remove the button from the
                    // MediaRouteButtonManager when the view is exiting the composition or being
                    // recomposed. Without these callbacks, the activity could become unresponsive
                    // after it comes back from the background (under certain conditions).
                    AndroidView(
                        factory = { _ -> mRButton },
                        onRelease = { MediaRouteButtonManager.remove(it) },
                        update = { updatedButton: CustomMediaRouteButton ->
                            if (updatedButton.isAttachedToWindow) {
                                MediaRouteButtonManager.add(updatedButton)
                            }
                        },
                        onReset = {}, // The necessary thing here is to have a non-null argument
                    )
                }
                // Your other composables, for example your main screen, or anything else
                AnotherComposable()
        }
    }
}

In our example above we've also specified the onReset callback, which is just a no-op in this case, but it's necessary to have a non-null argument there. It instructs compose that the given view should be reused when the view is moved or removed from the composition. To be honest, I still don't get why, but this was the only thing that fixed a weird issue on our side, when the app was in the background for a long time, and then it became unresponsive right after it came back to the foreground (without any errors in the logs).
The place where everything comes together
Although the necessary stuff are already in place, we need something that will encapsulate and expose the functionality we need, regarding casting. This is the place where you can put your custom logic, for example the logic that will fake a click on the button, load the media, etc. We call it CastContextManager in this example (and we use Koin for DI, but that's quite irrelevant, the only point is that you'll need a Context in there, but it doesn't matter how you pass it, or where you get it from):
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.google.android.gms.cast.MediaLoadRequestData
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastState
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastStateListener
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.RemoteMediaClient
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import org.koin.core.component.KoinComponent
import org.koin.core.component.inject

enum class CastDeviceState {
    CONNECTED,
    DISCONNECTED,
}

class CastContextManager : ViewModel(), KoinComponent {

    // Get the already initialized instance
    private val castCtx: CastContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance().apply {
        addCastStateListener(castStateListener())
    }

    /**
     * A reference to the RemoteMediaClient that is used to control the media on the connected
     * cast device.
     */
    private var remoteMediaClient: RemoteMediaClient? = null

    /**
     * The current state of the connected cast device.
     */
    private var deviceState by mutableStateOf(null as CastDeviceState?)

    // We use Koin, but you can pass a Context here on your own, it's up to you
    private val appContext: Context by inject()

    /**
     * Shows the expanded cast controls activity. The activity is started in a new task, so it
     * doesn't interfere with the current activity. This is necessary because the expanded cast
     * controls activity is a dialog-like activity.
     */
    private fun showExpandedControls() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val intent = Intent(appContext, ExpandedControlsActivity::class.java)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            appContext.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows either the device selector dialog (in case no device is connected) or the expanded
     * cast controls (in case a device is connected).
     */
    fun showDialog() {
        if (deviceState == CastDeviceState.CONNECTED) {
            showExpandedControls()
        } else {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                // Faking a click on the MediaRouteButton to show the device selector dialog
                MediaRouteButtonManager.current?.performClick()
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Loads the media on the connected cast device. The media is loaded with the given cast data.
     * After a successful loading, the expanded cast controls are shown.
     * In case of an error, the current cast session is forcefully ended & the "state" of the
     * CastContextManager is reset, just in case.
     */
    fun loadMedia() {
        try {
            val loadRequestData = MediaLoadRequestData.Builder()
                // Do your own stuff here, like providing the media URL, DRM info, the title, etc.
                .build()

            viewModelScope.launch {
                remoteMediaClient?.load(loadRequestData)
            }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            // Error during loading the media
            endSession()
            return
        }
        showExpandedControls()
    }

    /**
     * Ends the current cast session & resets the "state" of our CastContextManager
     */
    fun endSession() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                castCtx?.sessionManager?.endCurrentSession(true)
                remoteMediaClient = null
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                // Error during ending the cast session
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * CastStateListener that listens to the state of the Cast device
     */
    private fun castStateListener() = CastStateListener { state: Int ->
        when (state) {
            CastState.CONNECTED -> {
                remoteMediaClient = castCtx?.sessionManager?.currentCastSession?.remoteMediaClient
                remoteMediaClient?.stop()
                deviceState = CastDeviceState.CONNECTED
            }

            CastState.NOT_CONNECTED -> {
                // The NOT_CONNECTED state is emitted not only when the device is disconnected,
                // but as an initial state too (multiple times), so we only want to handle it,
                // when the device was previously connected.
                if (deviceState == CastDeviceState.CONNECTED) {
                    endSession()
                    deviceState = CastDeviceState.DISCONNECTED
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I think the comments are self-explanatory, you can fill the methods with your own logic, and you can also register additional listeners, based on your needs. You can also invoke the showDialog method from your Composables, for example from a button click, or from a gesture, etc.
One thing left to be clarified, and it's the expanded controls. You can see references in the code above to an ExpandedControlsActivity, which is a simple activity that shows the expanded controls. These controls are the ones, that are shown when a media is already playing on the cast device, and you can control the playback, the volume, etc. from there.
Setting up the expanded controls
First, you'll need a menu definition in your res/menu folder:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
        android:title="@string/media_route_menu_item"
        app:actionProviderClass="androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>

And an Activity:
import android.view.Menu
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastButtonFactory
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.ExpandedControllerActivity
import com.foo.R

/**
 * Activity that provides the expanded controls for the Cast SDK.
 */
class ExpandedControlsActivity : ExpandedControllerActivity() {
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.cast_expanded_controller_menu, menu)
        CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(this, menu, R.id.media_route_menu_item)
        return true
    }
}

Then you need to use it in your AndroidManifest.xml:
<activity android:name="com.foo.ExpandedControlsActivity" />

...and in your custom CastOptionsProvider, so it should look like this at the end:
import android.content.Context
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastOptions
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OptionsProvider
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.SessionProvider
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.CastMediaOptions
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.NotificationOptions

/**
 * Provides the CastOptions for the Cast SDK. Referenced in the AndroidManifest.xml.
 */
class CastOptionsProvider : OptionsProvider {
    override fun getCastOptions(context: Context): CastOptions {
        val notificationOptions = NotificationOptions.Builder()
            .setTargetActivityClassName(ExpandedControlsActivity::class.java.name)
            .build()
        val mediaOptions = CastMediaOptions.Builder()
            .setNotificationOptions(notificationOptions)
            .setExpandedControllerActivityClassName(ExpandedControlsActivity::class.java.name)
            .build()

        return CastOptions.Builder()
            .setReceiverApplicationId(context.getString({{YOUR_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID}}))
            .setCastMediaOptions(mediaOptions)
            .build()
    }

    override fun getAdditionalSessionProviders(context: Context): List<SessionProvider>? {
        return null
    }
}

That's it! With the code above you should be able now to:

provide your own Composable that would act as the SDK's built-in MediaRouteButton, or you can programmatically fake a click on it
show the device selector on the UI, and connect to a device
load media on the connected device
control the playback from the expanded controls
end the session manually, or it will be ended automatically when the device is disconnected

Originally, I've posted this on my blog, so you can read the whole story there, but the essence is pretty much what I wrote above, I hope it helps :)
